# discord.py 2.0.1 unban command

Tags: discord.py

I'm coding right now on a moderation bot and I tried to code a unban command but i got all the time the same error.
Maybe someone can help me.
Error:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.TransformerError: Failed to convert hello123#4650 to Member
```

My code:

```
    @app_commands.command(name="unban", description="unbans specified member.")
    @app_commands.default_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        successembed=discord.Embed(
            title="Success",
            description=f"{user.mention} has been unbanned."
        )
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=successembed)
```

I tried to add self. but it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The person you are unbanning is not a member (isn't in the server) because he's banned. Hence, you shouldn't be using `discord.Member`. However, you can use `discord.User`. The error was caused because you used the `discord.User` as the argument and it couldn't convert it to `discord.Member` as needed in the code.

```
@app_commands.command(name="unban", description="unbans specified member.")
@app_commands.default_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(self, ctx, user: discord.User): ##
    #rest of code
```